# Hide ScrollBar of the JScrollPane when user not touching JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, focus, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

This application is for a touch panel. 
I just need the scrollbar of the JScrollPane visible only when the user touches the JScrollPane area.

I am new to GUI and swing. It will be helpful, what are things, I am failing to understand or please provide the links if this question has been asked in a different forum.

**Edit 1**

As there was no effect by the first suggestion by @gthanop I would like be more specific.

My jscrollPane holds a panel which populates the subpanels dynamically. So, the focus should be for this panel.

**Edit 2**

The edit1 answer of @gthanop worked, but it works only on panel (jscrollPane viewport's view). Scrollbar disables when I hover or click on sub panel, which is populated on the same panel.

So, how to set jscrollPane viewport's view to the jpanel and also its contents? (This may be different question though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set whether each scrollbar is visible via the proper arguments in a method call of [`setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy-int-) and [`setVerticalScrollBarPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy-int-) on the [`JScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

You can do this inside a [`FocusListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) (which is for focus events such as when the focus is gained and lost) which will be installed in the contents of the `JScrollPane`, or to be more precise, in the `JScrollPane`'s `Viewport`'s view component (which is what the `JScrollPane` is scrolling).

Take for example the following code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class Main {
    private static void prepare(final JScrollPane scroll) {
        scroll.getViewport().getView().addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(final FocusEvent e) {
                scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(final FocusEvent e) {
                scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JTextArea area = new JTextArea("Type your messages here...");

        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));

        prepare(scroll);

        final JPanel components = new JPanel();
        components.add(new JButton("Click me to change focus!"));
        components.add(scroll);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll auto focus.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(components);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When you click at the button of the frame that pops up, the focus will be lost from the view of the `Viewport` of the `JScrollPane` and the scrollbars will hide. After that, when you click back inside the `JTextArea` (which in this case is the `JScrollPane`'s `Viewport`'s view component) the focus will be regained in it, so you simply show the scrollbars with the appropriate method call.

### Edit 1

As I understood from the comments of this answer, you need to show the scrollbars when the user hovers the mouse over the `JScrollPane`'s `Viewport`'s view. If so, in this case, you can add a [`MouseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to the view like so:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class MainMouse {
    private static void prepare(final JScrollPane scroll) {
        scroll.getViewport().getView().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(final MouseEvent e) {
                scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(final MouseEvent e) {
                scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JTextArea area = new JTextArea("Type your messages here...");

        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));

        prepare(scroll);

        final JPanel components = new JPanel();
        components.add(new JButton("Click me to change focus!"));
        components.add(scroll);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroll auto focus.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(components);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Now when you hover over the `JTextArea` then the scrollbars will appear. When you hover outside the `JTextArea` then the scrollbars will disappear.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply. I understood, what you are suggesting. It should work but no luck bro!

Comment: @AnandNarayan you mean it doesn't work? I tested it before posting. It works for me. Also tested it now. You just have to click inside the JTextArea to gain focus (and the scrollbars will appear if they did not already) and then click on the button to lose focus from the JTextArea (which will in turn make the scrollbars disappear).

Comment: I will be more clear about my application. Actually, I have a scroll pane, whose view set to  a jpanel, which consists of various subpanels that are dynamically populated. But the suggested focus listener not working in this case.

Comment: I assume the hovering over the panel also, grabs the focus. Anyhow I even tried clicking on the panel as well. But still, no luck yet!

Comment: @AnandNarayan I think then we need to be provided by some code of yours, in order to understand what you are after. You can update your question. If you want the hovering over the panel to show the scrollbars, then this is a different requirement and I will update my answer and notify you.

Comment: @AnandNarayan have a look at my updated answer... The second code in the answer adds a MouseListener to the view so as to add the hovering effect of the mouse over the JTextArea.

Comment: I'm really sorry. As I said, I was designing for touch panel. So, there should be no question of hovering over the panel.  Since, presently I was testing on my PC, I misdirected the question. I'm very sorry. But, thanks a lot!!!. Same code working for the same.

Comment: @AnandNarayan oh ok. I'm not used to use touch screens in laptops/PCs (just using mouse all the time). So that maybe confused me. Oups. Thanks for accepting. Although if it was not what you are looking for I think you can undo your accepting, so others will have a look also at this question if you are still interested in it.

Comment: But, as I said jscrollPane holds a jpanel(which is set as jscrollPane viewport view) in which the subpanels are being populated. So, the scrollbar activates only on jpanel(empty space) and it gets disabled when it touch on subpanel, which is populated  inside the same jpanel.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, since it answers my primary question. The sub question or new different question added in the edit.

Comment: @AnandNarayan according to your second edit you have panels inside the panel which is inside the JScrollPane. Correct? If so, then you just need to add the same MouseListener inside every panel which populates the main panel. Can you provide an example code you are trying to make work?

Comment: just thinking about the same and saw your reply. Implemented and working like a charm.  Thanks!